# SQL table structure relationship feedback

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables in my sql. I want to have you guys feedback on how I am building my tables relationship. So I have 4 tables: application_table, teacher_table, student_table and class_table.

Here are several conditions:

1. A teacher can teach one or many class, but there also teacher teachers 0 class. (1 -> N, teacher -> class_table) relationship. One thing to notice is a teacher may leave the school.
2. A student can attend many class. One thing to notice is that a student may get expelled or graduated. (1 -> N student-> class)
3. An application can be used by many student, and a student can use many application. (N -> N relationship)
4. An application can be used by many teacher, and also a teacher can use many application. (N -> N relationship)

ps. An application may be cut or expired or not used by the school anymore.

**application_table**

```
 applicationId
 applicationName
 expiryDate
```

**teacher and class relationship**

```
 class_table
   classId
   classCode
   teacherId
```

**Student and class relationship**

```
student_table
  studentId 
  firstName
  lastName
  classId
```

**application and teacher relationship**

```
  application_teacher
     applicationId
     teacherId
```

**application and student relationship**

```
 appliaction_student
   applicationId
   studentId
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should first study normalization. One good source is the wikipedia. Your structures are against normalization (ie: Student - Class shouldn't have firstName, lastName ).

A 'school' database is more complex than this but your structures might work for a sandbox learning application, provided you correct the normalization problems.

Comment: Hi Cetin, thank you for your reply. I thought my student - class is alright because one class can be attend my many students so it should be 1->N and I add the classId as a foreign key to demonstrate this is a 1-> N relationship

Comment: No, it is not alright. The problem is that, you have studentId and classId to support Many-To-Many relation (it is "bridge" table). Student's firstName, lastName or Class' classCode doesn't belong there (just the foreign keys).

Comment: Can you provide an example of how I should fix it? thanks. because I am new to sql

Comment: As I said, remove firstName, lastName from that table. Only keep the foreign keys (and additional fields that doesn't belong to student or class table if any - ie: enrollmentDate). Please take your time to read and understand normalization on wikipedia.